# Find matches in string PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table per_1 with thousands of records

What I'm looking for is to do a right-to-left SELECT that matches the most similar numbers regardless of whether they are in disarray at the end of each string, I do **not** use LIKE '' because it would return exactly the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Table per_1

id permutation

1 00021478200123456789

2 14782297690213564987

3 02897452205987425631

The last 9 numbers are the same, only they are in disorder, I need a query that returns precisely those 3 columns or all similar, containing 123456789 at the end, regardless of the order in which they are at the end of each chain.

I do not need LIKE '' because it will return a row exactly the same, and what I look for are the most similar terminations, not the exact ones.

I have a Postgresql 9.4 in windows 10

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us some sample data along with what output you expect.  I don't think your `LIKE` expression should have whitespace in it, as a side note.

Comment: you need to add some test data, showing both the kinds of records that you *want* to match, and the kinds that you *don't want* to match

Comment: You should add data sample and not image.

Comment: could you please elaborate question with more clear samples of data and desired matches - please use shorter strings

Comment: If you search for `452230` should it return also something like `442305502`?

Comment: It is correct Łukasz, and all similarities

Comment: I'm trying to make a more detailed example, with the respective spaces and details, I apologize because I know it's not the most correct way I've used it, but I'm new to this page and every time I try to generate a space in the box Understand that I want to upload my comment

Comment: Do **not** post code, sample data or additional information in comments. **[edit]** your question instead

Answer (score 0):

You could split that string into array of chars and compare.

```
Select Permutation
From per_1
Where regexp_split_to_array(permutation, '') @> regexp_split_to_array('45022003', '')
```

You can possibly speed this up if you create GIN/GiST index with expression

```
create index per_1_split_idx ON per_1 USING gin(regexp_split_to_array(permutation, ''));
```

Comment: Your SQL query returns all types of rows, some contain "45022003" anywhere in the row (at the beginning or end), instead the idea is for matches to be searched at the end of each row. Thank you very much for your interest.